# Невозможно симулировать локацию в Xcode Version 9.0.1 (9A1004)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Всем привет! Я работаю над проектом, где очень часто нужно менять локацию пользователя, разумеется я включил все необходимые данные для симуляции локации с самого начала проекта. Сегодня Xcode не симулируют custom location, я решил попробовать сможет ли он симулировать одну из стандартных локаций (например San Francisco), но когда я запускаю приложение на реальном устройстве, то на реальном устройстве отображается моя реальная локация. Я пробовал запускать приложение на симуляторе, но получил такой же результат. Я делал clean project, перезагружал реальное устройство (iPhone 7), перезагружал Xcode но результатов это не дало. Я прочитал несколько топиков, но все они относились к тому, что разработчики не включали симуляцию локации в scheme. Как я могу исправить данную проблему? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После запуска пробовали выбирать simulate locations и указывать город/gpx: http://pastenow.ru/53ab3123965e19f17b5c397b705ed294 ?

Comment: @VAndrJ да пробовал, после обновление на версию Version 9.1 (9B55) данной проблема была только один раз, но ее смог исправить обычным перезапуском Xcode

Comment: У меня в Xcode 8+ подобное было, лечилось запуском другого симулятора, в Xcode 9+ еще не ловил. В общем, не все идеально, баги везде.